# Are there any drawbacks ( things to care ) when using dynamic queries in stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures, dynamic-queries

I am developing website using asp.net.

I have a situation Where I need to query a table based on several filter mechanisms driven by check-boxes in interface using SQL. So there may be several combinations for filters. So Finally I figured out that this can be achieve by using dynamic sql queries. So I wrote a stored procedure and then pass queries to stored procedure from the app after generating the right query.

My sample stored procedure will be like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_dynamic(IN query_one VARCHAR(500))
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT col1,col2 FROM test_table where',query_one );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

So I have few questions

1) Is this safe? I mean will it lead to sql injections?

2) Stored procedure are always compiled to best query plan. So dynamic queries will lead to recompile the SP when each time it got a query right?

3) IS there any performance issues?

4) Is there any other facts should I need to care when I use this approach?

5) **If there any issues what actions can be take to minimize those things?**

Comment: Nothing changes just because you construct the query on the server. The exact same problems apply. Preparing and deallocating the statement don't help either - they are doing exactly what the server would do

Comment: I think there is an confusion: stored procedures are compiled; queries are run according query plans. Compilation of SP avoids parsing and interpreting it each time it is run. Query plan avoids decisions like which index to use or not, which table to scan or not, etc. These are completely independent concepts. In your particular case, the master procedure will get compiled, and the dynamic SQL will be matched against existing query plan if possible. The fact you are slapping together this query ad hoc is irrelevant, it only matters if an existing query plan looks applicable to a query.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changes just because you construct the query on the server. The exact same problems apply. The problem is the use of "dynamic sql" itself, not where it's executed

Specifically:

1. Security hasn't improved. One can still pass `1=1;drop table users;--` as an input.
2. All SQL code gets compiled to a query plan. Stored procedures don't result in a *better* plan. The benefit is that you can reuse a stored procedure's plan *unless* the queries it executes change. That's the case with programmatically constructed statements of conditionals that execute different queries. So you don't get any query plan benefits either.
3. Performance isn't improved at all. Whether you explicitly prepare the statement or let the query optimizer create the plan, each individual query will have to be compiled.

In fact, a parameterized query sent from the client would be safer and perform better,  as injections would be prevented and the query optimizer would be able to create and reuse a parameterized query plan

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection is possible as soon there is dynamic SQL which is handled carelessly(without parameters), be that SQL statements sent from the client, dynamic SQL generated in T-SQL stored procedures, or SQL batches executed from CLR stored procedures.

Another advantage with stored procedures over SQL sent from the client is that less bytes travel the network. Rather than sending a 50-line query over the network, you only need to pass the name of a stored procedure and a few parameters. This gets more significant if the computation requires several queries, possibly with logic in between. If all logic is outside the database, this could mean that data has to travel up to the client, only to travel back in the next moment.

Hence performance is considered here.

Follow [these](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#good_practices) practices for better dynamic queries